# Can I use a custom listview layout in a simple cursor adapte?

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I´d like to know if there is a way to use a simple cursor adapter to use both a custom listview and allow multiple selection, I currently have the following 2 codes working:

```
final ListView list = getListView();
    list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    //list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    // initialize the adapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            //android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
            null,
            new String[]{DBHelper.C_NAME},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
```

And this

```
Cursor cursor = dataSourceAdapter.fetchAllEntries();

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] {"_id", "ASUNTO", "FECHA", "INFO"};

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.tvID,
            R.id.tvAsunto,
            R.id.tvFecha,
            R.id.tvInfo
    };

dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.lvitems,
            cursor,
            Tasks.COLUMNS,
            to,
            0);
```

Both codes work fine but I´d like to add multiple choice to the latter using my lvitems laoyout.

Thanks for your help.